# How to dynamically import a file based on user input

Tags: javascript, npm, es6-modules

I'm writing an npm module and want to allow users to create a config file to control how the command line calls to this module run. How can I import this config file reliably? Ideally this should work in development using NPM link as well as in production.

Example file structure:

```
- project folder
  - node_modules
    - my_module
      - cli.mjs (Where the command line processing is running)
  - k.config.mjs
```

So, ideally, I want to reliably be able to import `my.config.mjs` if it exists. I've tried several ways of using the dynamic import. The most(?) successful has been:

```js
const baseDir = process.cwd();
const configPath = path.resolve(baseDir,'./k.config.mjs');
const configURL = new URL(configPath);
const userOpts = import(configURL.pathname);
console.log('userOpts',userOpts);
```

This gives me an error though (using npm link):

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_MODULE_SPECIFIER]: Invalid module "\Git\Kurohyou_studios\inittest\k.config.mjs" is not a valid package name imported from E:\Git\Kurohyou_studios\k-scaffold\cli.mjs
```

So, what's the proper way for me to dynamically import this config file?

Comment: Are you sure that the directory you call this package has the file `k.config.mjs`?

Comment: Yes, it has the config file in it. But while confirming that I stumbled on a solution. Apparently if I do configURL.pathname.replace(/\\/g,'/'), it works.